# firebase notification not showing in snackbar while app closed android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to show **firebase push notification(sending firebase console) in activity's snackbar by broadcast** receiver which i get from **FirebaseMessagingService** but i am unable to show.please help me.

Manifest:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

firebase message service:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        if(remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
            Log.v("Message data", remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        }

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            Log.v("MessageNotification", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody().toString());
        }

        if(remoteMessage!=null){
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.toString());
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody){

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,NotificationShowActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("FireBaseNotification",messageBody);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

notificationShow Activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification_show);

        linearLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_notification_show);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter(MyFirebaseMessagingService.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));

    }

    //broadcastReceiver

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String message=intent.getStringExtra("FireBaseNotification");
            if(message!=null){

                Toast.makeText(NotificationShowActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: how are u sending the data, is it using the Firebase console or you have implemented your own server? is it showing on your Log statements?

Comment: are the Log statements showing up in your Android Monitor?

Comment: yes........,,,,

Comment: implement your own server

Answer (score 0):

To catch FCM messages in background your should use receiver, not service.

```
public class NotificationsReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //handle your data
        abortBroadcast(); //stop sending this broadcast to other receivers.
    }
}
```

In your manifest (important - set priority to 999, to be first in receivers queue):

```
<receiver
        android:name=".fcm.NotificationsReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```